# about Tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter

why i can not run this?

`top.geometry('250*150')`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\canux\Desktop\myCode\pythonMy\cpp\guitest.py", line 10, in <module>
    top.geometry('250*150')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1659, in wm_geometry
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'geometry', self._w, newGeometry)
TclError: bad geometry specifier "250*150"
```

Comment: Did you actually read your error message? It's telling you what the problem is. Are you under the impression that `250*150` should be a valid geometry specification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the python tkinter documentation, with regards to geometry:

> geometry
>
> This is a string of the form `widthxheight`, where width and height are measured in pixels for most widgets (in characters for widgets displaying text). For example: `fred["geometry"] = "200x100"`.

I believe the reason for this and not a simpler way of determining dimension is because Tkinter is a wrapper around Tcl/Tk, so some conventions stuck.

Comment: Oh. I get it. width    'X'    height + x + y.

Comment: Why do yo think widthxheight` sucks? This seems like a completely natural way to specify the size of a window. The reason isn't because tkinter is a wrapper around tcl/tk _per se_, but because it's based on code that was originally intended for X11 systems only, and that's how you specify geometry for a window on X11 windows.

Comment: I feel having a function that would take a height and width as named parameters is more readable and less error prone. I did not say that it "sucks", but rather that there should be something simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Try `'250x150'` instead of `'250*150'`

Comment: Yes, that is right. Thank you. But why? And how can i print 'x' by the keybord

Answer (score 0):

I thought that the format for using "geometry" method is like this:

**top.geometry("width × height")**

**×** is multiplication sign. (you can enter multiplication sign using Alt + 0215)

but finally i noticed that it is:

**top.geometry("width x height")**

**x** is the x character not the multiplication sign!!

you can find very useful information here:
http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/geometry.html